# Adding left margin to UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm trying to add a left margin to a UITextView.

I've tried setting the property contentInset, see below:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
textView.editable = YES;
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.opaque = NO;
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15.0f, 0, 0);
```

This seems to work though it causes horizontal scrolling on the TextView which I don't want.

I just want the text inset on the left without making the textview any wider.

Comment: I misread the question or it must be the sleep catching on. I have deleted my answer now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Since it derives from uiscrollview, you can independently controlling the scrolling action. However since you require scrolling, you can try setting the framesize = actualframesize - inset in the horizontal direction. This is just a suggestion which you can try.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you only want to move the text, try

```
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];
```

Where a positive number moves the "text frame" towards the middle, a negative moves it out from the middle.

For example, `[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0,-20)]`, will move the text 20 pixels to the right!

Answer (score 23):

Remember that for iOS 7 there a special property called

> textContainerInset The inset of the text container's layout area
>   within the text view's content area.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign) UIEdgeInsets textContainerInset
>
> This property provides text margins for text laid out in
>   the text view.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later. Declared In UITextView.h

in iOS 6 the contentInset is doing the job. I personally encountered this problem. Everything ended up with:

```
if (isIOS7()) {
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
} else {
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
}
```

Comment: Argh! At last! Was wondering why it wasn't working on iOS 7. Thanks.

Comment: textContainerInset worked wonders for me.  contentInset on my iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1) was not working, but textContainerInset worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY thing worked for me is by sub-classing the UITextView and overriding the following method:

```
    - (id)styleString
{
    return [[super styleString] stringByAppendingString:@"; line-height: 1.6em;margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 45px; margin-top: 20px;"];
}
```

Apparently; you can tweak the margin-left, margin-top & whatever you want ;)

---

The suggestion about placing the UITextView in a larger UIView didn't work for me as I needed to scrollable lines in the background of UITextView, I used the following open-source project to do that:
https://github.com/aahsanali/NoteView

Also, the following solution didn't help me at all:

```
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0,-20)]
```

As it wasn't wrapping text correctly.

I hope this solution helps as I literally spent a week digging into this simple UI tweak!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code below with **Swift 3.0**

```
// Align the text to the left edge of textContainer
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 16
// Align the text with the top of textContainer
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier if you do it via IB. Find the panel named **Scroll View Size** & set the Content Insets.

In code, you can try setting `scrollEnabled` to NO.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` is internally implemented using a web view. These internals uses allot of undocumented tricks, that also changes between OS updates. One of these tricks is to time and again *reset* the `contentInsets` property. When and why is not documented, by I have learned that any changes to the layout of the text view can/will trigger this reset.

My first advice would be to not try to tweak the insets of the text view. It is just to fragile, and will probably break in the future.

If you really insist anyway then I would subclass `UITextView`, override `-[UITextView layoutSubviews]` and force new insets there.

In either case I would go to http://bugreport.apple.com and report the current behavior as serious bug.