# How can I modify the display rect in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

[image]

As the pic above,I want to make the text left-aligned with the label,how to do that?

Comment: To change the text margin use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010036/adding-left-margin-to-uitextview

Comment: Use constraints. Pin Label to the edge with a known margin and to the top with a known margin. Pin top of text to bottom of label with whatever size you want. Then finally align the leading edges of the label and the text. Set the width and height you want for the text or pin its trailing and bottom edges to the container view. Again set the pin value to your margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set edge insect for text container. Here is the line of code

[textView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];

Or you can use property 'setContentInset' to set the margin as suggested above.